# SwipeRefreshLayout and ListView action detection

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

So I'm currently working on a bit not-ideal legacy Android project and I'm trying to solve this inconsistency regarding `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `ListView`. Both of these views are added programmatically as follows:

```
// lv is ListView initiated elsewhere.
mSwipeRefreshLayout = new SwipeRefreshLayout(this);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.addView(lv);
```

Pull-to-refresh and anything related to `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `ListView` actions are working as expected. But, if I'm scrolling with intention to trigger pull-to-refresh mechanism:

- On portrait, my `ListView` fires up `onScroll` but NOT through `onScrollStateChanged` whereas if I'm scrolling up (moving `ListView` contents up) I get the expected event sequence from `ListView`.
- On landscape, I didn't receive any scroll event on the `ListView` unless I'm scrolling up (moving `ListView` contents up) which is what I wanted.

Does anyone have an idea or a pointer for me to start looking for the solution? I figured that somewhere, some code part triggered a scroll but I've been at it for almost a day now and cannot find it and started to think that I might be barking on a wrong tree.

Thank you.